# Problem with selecting columns within selected columns using RadioButtons in ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, dashboard, dt

I'm building a **shinyApp using R**. I'm using **radioButtons** to select columns, and then using *radiobuttons again* to select further columns within previous selected columns.
I'm unable to do so as i get an error whenever i select anything other than **All** from **choose variable', 'choose waves'  & 'choose wave'**.

I believe the *problem lies* in the **reactive part of server**.
Can someone please have a look at my codes? I shall be extremely grateful :)

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(DT)

data_table<-mtcars[,c(2,8,1,3,4,5,9,6,7, 10,11)]

data_table$disp<-NULL

names(data_table)[3:10]<- rep(x = 
c('TS_lhr_Wave_1','TS_isb_Wave_2','TS_quta_Wave_1','TS_karach_Wave_2', 

'NTS_lhr_Wave_1','NTS_isb_Wave_2','NTS_quta_Wave_1','NTS_karach_Wave_2'), 
times=1, each=1)



# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
downloadButton('downLoadFilter',"Download the filtered data"),

radioButtons(inputId = "columns", label = "choose variable",
           choices =c("All","TS", "NTS"), inline =TRUE,
           selected = c("TS")),

radioButtons(inputId = "regions", label = "choose region",
           choices =c("All", "lhr", "isb", "quta", "karach"), inline = TRUE,
           selected = c("lhr")),

radioButtons(inputId = "waves", label = "choose wave",
           choices =c("All", "Wave_1", "Wave_2"), inline = TRUE,
           selected = c("Wave_1")),


selectInput(inputId = "cyl",
          label = "cyl:",
          choices = c("All",
                      unique(as.character(data_table$cyl))),
          selected = "All",
          multiple = TRUE),


selectInput(inputId = "vs",
          label = "vs:",
          choices = c("All",
                      unique(as.character(data_table$vs))),
          selected = "All",
          multiple = TRUE),

DT::dataTableOutput('ex1'))


# Define Server
server <- function(input, output) {

thedata <- reactive({

if(input$cyl != 'All'){
  data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in%   input$cyl,]
}

if(input$vs != 'All'){
  data_table<-data_table[data_table$vs %in%  input$vs,]
}


#TS NTS
if  (input$columns== 'TS'){
  data_table<-  data_table[,c(1,2, 3,4,5,6),drop=FALSE]    }


if  (input$columns== 'NTS'){
  data_table<-  data_table[,c(1,2,7,8,9,10),drop=FALSE]    }



#region
if  (input$regions== 'lhr' ){
  data_table<-  data_table[,c(1,2,3,7),
                           drop=FALSE]    }

if  (input$regions== 'isb' ){
  data_table<-  data_table[,c(1,2,4,8),
                           drop=FALSE]    }


if  (input$regions== 'quta' ){
  data_table<-  data_table[,c(1,2,5,9),
                           drop=FALSE]    }


if  (input$regions== 'karach' ){
  data_table<-  data_table[,c(1,2,6,10),
                           drop=FALSE]    }


#waves
if  (input$waves== 'Wave_1' ){
  data_table<-  data_table[,c(1,2,3,5,7, 9),
                           drop=FALSE]    }

if  (input$waves== 'Wave_2' ){
  data_table<-  data_table[,c(1,2,4,6, 8, 10),
                           drop=FALSE]    }


else
  data_table })

output$ex1 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(filter = 'top',
                                              escape = FALSE, 
                                              options = list(pageLength = 
                                                               10, 

scrollX='500px',autoWidth = TRUE),{
                                                               thedata()  
}))

output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste('Filtered data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
},
content = function(path){
  write_csv(thedata(),path)   })}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes you're problem is in the reactive or more specific in your logic of if-conditions. You filter for columns by index and it will try to filter for columns which arent at hand anymore, because they got filtered out in a previous if-statement. You will have to adapt all those conditions and maybe filter by columnname instead of indices.

Comment: For example if you filter the table for TS or NTS columns, then in your region selection, you filter again for TS **and** NTS columns, but one of them wont be available anymore as they were filtered out already. So the region and waves filter are only possible if variable is set to *All*.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks a lot for the help. Is it possible for you to update the codes? As i tried to sort it out, but didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly how you want to build that logic, but here is an example of how to disable and enable some inputs. It still throws some eror in the console, but at least everything is shown correctly in the App.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

data_table<-mtcars[,c(2,8,1,3,4,5,9,6,7, 10,11)]

data_table$disp<-NULL

names(data_table)[3:10]<- rep(x = 
                                c('TS_lhr_Wave_1','TS_isb_Wave_2','TS_quta_Wave_1','TS_karach_Wave_2',                                  
                                  'NTS_lhr_Wave_1','NTS_isb_Wave_2','NTS_quta_Wave_1','NTS_karach_Wave_2'), 
                              times=1, each=1)


# Define UI
ui <- {fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  downloadButton('downLoadFilter',"Download the filtered data"),

  radioButtons(inputId = "columns", label = "choose variable",
               choices =c("All","TS", "NTS"), inline =TRUE,
               selected = c("All")),

  radioButtons(inputId = "regions", label = "choose region",
               choices =c("All", "lhr", "isb", "quta", "karach"), inline = TRUE,
               selected = c("All")),

  radioButtons(inputId = "waves", label = "choose wave",
               choices =c("All", "Wave_1", "Wave_2"), inline = TRUE,
               selected = c("All")),


  selectInput(inputId = "cyl",
              label = "cyl:",
              choices = c("All",
                          unique(as.character(data_table$cyl))),
              selected = "All",
              multiple = TRUE),


  selectInput(inputId = "vs",
              label = "vs:",
              choices = c("All",
                          unique(as.character(data_table$vs))),
              selected = "All",
              multiple = TRUE),

  DT::dataTableOutput('ex1', width="100%")
)}


# Define Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    if (input$columns != "All") {
      updateRadioButtons(session, "regions", selected = "All")
      updateRadioButtons(session, "waves", selected = "All")

      shinyjs::disable("regions")
      shinyjs::disable("waves")
    } else {
      shinyjs::enable("regions")
      shinyjs::enable("waves")
    }

    if (input$regions != "All") {
      shinyjs::disable("waves")
    }
    if (input$waves != "All") {
      shinyjs::disable("regions")
    }
  })



  thedata <- reactive({

    #TS NTS
    if  (input$columns == 'TS'){
      data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl","vs", "TS_lhr_Wave_1", "TS_isb_Wave_2", "TS_quta_Wave_1", "TS_karach_Wave_2"),drop=FALSE]    }
    if  (input$columns == 'NTS'){
      data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl","vs","NTS_lhr_Wave_1", "NTS_isb_Wave_2","NTS_quta_Wave_1", "NTS_karach_Wave_2"),drop=FALSE]    }

    #waves
    if  (input$waves == 'Wave_1' ){
      data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl","vs","TS_lhr_Wave_1","TS_quta_Wave_1","NTS_lhr_Wave_1", "NTS_quta_Wave_1"), drop=FALSE]    }
    if  (input$waves == 'Wave_2' ){
      data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl","vs","TS_isb_Wave_2","TS_karach_Wave_2", "NTS_isb_Wave_2", "NTS_karach_Wave_2"), drop=FALSE]    }

    #region
    if  (input$regions == 'lhr' ){
      data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl","vs","TS_lhr_Wave_1","NTS_lhr_Wave_1"), drop=FALSE]    }
    if  (input$regions == 'isb' ){
      data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl","vs","TS_isb_Wave_2","NTS_isb_Wave_2"), drop=FALSE]    }
    if  (input$regions == 'quta' ){
      data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl","vs","TS_quta_Wave_1","NTS_quta_Wave_1"), drop=FALSE]    }
    if  (input$regions == 'karach' ){
      data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl","vs","TS_karach_Wave_2","NTS_karach_Wave_2"), drop=FALSE]    }

    ## cyl / vs
    if (any(input$cyl != 'All')){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in%   input$cyl,] 
    }
    if(any(input$vs != 'All')){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$vs %in%  input$vs,]
    }

    req(data_table)

    data_table
  })

  output$ex1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(thedata())

    DT::datatable(filter = 'top', escape = FALSE, width = "100%",
                  options = list(pageLength =  10, 
                                 scrollX='500px',autoWidth = TRUE),{
                                   thedata()  
                                 })
  })

  output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('Filtered data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
    },
    content = function(path){
      write_csv(thedata(),path)   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```